# PHP - split a string of HTML attributes into an indexed array

Tags: php, split, html

I've got a string with HTML attributes:

```
$attribs = ' id= "header " class = "foo   bar" style ="background-color:#fff; color: red; "';
```

How to transform that string into an indexed array, like:

```
array(
  'id' => 'header',
  'class' => array('foo', 'bar'),
  'style' => array(
    'background-color' => '#fff',
    'color' => 'red'
  )
)
```

so I can use the PHP array_merge_recursive function to merge 2 sets of HTML attributes.

Thank you

Answer (score 24):

Use SimpleXML:

```
<?php
$attribs = ' id= "header " class = "foo   bar" style ="background-color:#fff; color: red; "';

$x = new SimpleXMLElement("<element $attribs />");

print_r($x);

?>
```

This assumes that the attributes are always name/value pairs...

Answer (score 8):

You could use a regular expression to extract that information:

```
$attribs = ' id= "header " class = "foo   bar" style ="background-color:#fff; color: red; "';
$pattern = '/(\\w+)\s*=\\s*("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'\\s>]*)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $attribs, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$attrs = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if (($match[2][0] == '"' || $match[2][0] == "'") && $match[2][0] == $match[2][strlen($match[2])-1]) {
        $match[2] = substr($match[2], 1, -1);
    }
    $name = strtolower($match[1]);
    $value = html_entity_decode($match[2]);
    switch ($name) {
    case 'class':
        $attrs[$name] = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($value));
        break;
    case 'style':
        // parse CSS property declarations
        break;
    default:
        $attrs[$name] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($attrs);
```

Now you just need to parse the classes of `class` (split at whitespaces) and property declarations of `style` (a little bit harder as it can contain comments and URLs with `;` in it).

Comment: Thank you Gumbo, your regex is cool.

The only problem is $attrs['class'] or $attrs['style'] are returning strings: so it will be difficult to merge them with another $attribs string, for example merging that 2 sets of attribs:
$attribs1 = 'class="foo bar"';
$attribs2 = 'class="lorem"';
into a 'class="foo bar lorem"'

That's why I would like $attrs['class'] returns an array: array('foo', 'bar')

Do you have an idea to enhance this?

Comment: I've just written an alternative regex which also parses HTML5 style boolean attributes (without an = sign) and uses a back reference for the quotes: `(\w+)\s*(=\s*(["'])(.*?)\2\s)?`

Answer (score 7):

Easy way could be also:

```
$atts_array = current((array) new SimpleXMLElement("<element $attribs />"));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use a regular expression to parse html-attributes. This is because the syntax is contextual. You can use regular expressions to tokenize the input, but you need a state machine to parse it.

If the performance isn't a big deal, the safest way to do it, is probably to wrap the attributes in a tag and then send it through an html parser. Eg.:

```
function parse_attributes($input) {
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->loadHtml("<foo " . $input. "/>");
  $attributes = array();
  foreach ($dom->documentElement->attributes as $name => $attr) {
    $attributes[$name] = $node->value;
  }
  return $attributes;
}
```

You could probably optimize the above, by reusing the parser, or by using [XmlReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) or the [sax parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Comment: Parse this: foo='bar' cuux="O'Reiley" zip="\"zap\""

Comment: @troelskn: The third attribute value declaration is invalid. The `"` need to be represented by character references.

Comment: You're right - I wasn't aware of that. I would still suggest using an xml/html parser, to account for all sorts of odd edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

May be this helps you .. 
What it does ..

- A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
- Require PHP 5+.
- Supports invalid HTML.
- Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
- Extract contents from HTML in a single line.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note that the one reason I ended up here is because the DOMProcessingInstruction has a `data` field which is the text wihin the `<?name` and `?>`. In case of a tag such as: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="https://sms.m2osw.com/sitemap.xsl"?>` you get a plain string like: `type="text/xsl" href="https://sms.m2osw.com/sitemap.xsl"` which you need to parse as attributes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and effective function to solve this

```
function attrString2Array($attr) {
  $atList = [];

  if (preg_match_all('/\s*(?:([a-z0-9-]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)")|(?:\s+([a-z0-9-]+)(?=\s*|>|\s+[a..z0-9]+))/i', $attr, $m)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($m[0]); $i++) {
      if ($m[3][$i])
        $atList[$m[3][$i]] = null;
      else
        $atList[$m[1][$i]] = $m[2][$i];
    }
  }

  return $atList;
}

print_r(attrString2Array('<li data-tpl-classname="class" data-tpl-title="innerHTML" disabled nowrap href="#" hide src = "images/asas.gif">'));
print_r(attrString2Array('data-tpl-classname="class" data-tpl-title="innerHTML" disabled nowrap href="#" hide src = "images/asas.gif"'));

//Array
//(
//    [data-tpl-classname] => class
//    [data-tpl-title] => innerHTML
//    [disabled] => 
//    [nowrap] => 
//    [href] => #
//    [hide] => 
//    [src] => images/asas.gif
//)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to provide an explanation of your code. This will improve your answer's quality and make it more likely for it to get upvoted :)

Comment: Did you notice that the OP's question is seeking a multi-dimensional result?