# Replace every white space character between quotes

Tags: php, regex

Ok I found an answer
[PHP - split a string of HTML attributes into an indexed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083792/php-split-a-string-of-html-attributes-into-an-indexed-array#answer-1083799)

Thank's

I wanna replace every white space character between quotes with `%20`

Example:

```
<input type="text" title="this is a fish">
```

Desired result:

```
<input type="text" title="this%20is%20a%20fish">
```

Another example

```
$_POST['foo'] = '<input type="text" title="this is a fish">';
$parsed = '<input type="text" title="this%20is%20a%20fish">';
```

As seen I only whant to replace the spaces within the qoutes, not any other.
So `str_replace` simply will not help here

The desierd end result of this is an array of the parameters

This is what I did

```
<?php
$tag_parsed = trim($tag_parsed);
$tag_parsed = str_replace('"', '', $tag_parsed);
$tag_parsed = str_replace(' ', '&', $tag_parsed);
parse_str($tag_parsed, $tag_parsed);
```

But when a parameter has a space, it breaks.

Comment: <?php
$str = 'foo   o';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
// This will be 'foo o' now
echo $str;
?> output->foo o

Comment: @DenisAlexandrov that is not what I'm asking, I have a string like in the example, I don't want to replace every white-space, just the ones in the qoutes

Comment: @MordiSacks, however, the functions' are same. You just have to properly use them. Example: `<input type="text" title="<?= str_replace(' ', '%20', 'this is a fish') ?>">`

Comment: Again, I don't create the string, I receive it, so I cannot call a function within it

Comment: Could you update your questions with this process, so we could have an idea on what's going on?

Comment: @MordiSacks check my update

Comment: Did anybody find a real answer to the original question? 
"I wanna replace every white space character between quotes with %20"  . 

The "real" answer should work regardless of the string being an HTML tag or not. In my case, I have this string (i put it in brackets to prevent confusion with qoutes): 

(* LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "/" "Posta indesiderata")  

Items are sperated by spaces, but a space also appears in last item, so how do I properly separate the items so I get 6 items rather than 7?

Maybe I should open an other question?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Basing on your last comments, it seems you need something like this:

```
$str = '<input type="text" title="this is a fish">';
preg_match('/title="(.*)"/', $str, $title);
$parsed_title = str_replace(' ', '%20', $title[1]);
```

But it seems there's something could be done to improve tre rest of the code.

---

You have to use `urlencode` or similiar function:

```
$str = "Your spaced string";
$new = urlencode($str); //Your%20spaced%20string
```

Or, use `preg_replace`:

```
$str = "Your spaced string";
$new = preg_replace("/\s+/", "%20", $str);
```

OR, without regexp:

```
$new = str_replace(" ", "%20", $str);
```

Comment: That does not help me, because when i have the string it is as in the example, not just the text

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Try `preg_replace` or `str_replace`. And, check the dup link