# Check if attribute hreflang exists

Tags: php, attr, hreflang

I would like to check if the hreflang attribute exists, I am not sure what the best method is? Is `preg_match` the only method or is there more?

```
function add_hreflang() {
    if( !($attribute['hreflang']) ){
        // do something
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_hreflang', 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `!empty()` check

```
function add_hreflang() {
  if( !empty($attribute['hreflang']) ){
    // do something
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
To check if any specific attribute is present you can use following code it converts your html element to xml object and then xml to array and find out if the attribute you need exists in the array. link to the orignal [html to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083792/php-split-a-string-of-html-attributes-into-an-indexed-array) and [xml to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167279/converting-a-simplexml-object-to-an-array) code.

```
$str = '<a href="http://example.com" anotherAttrib="someValue">Link</a>';

$link = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
// print_r($link);

function xml2array( $xmlObject, $out = array () ){
    foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
        $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

    return $out;
}


$arr = xml2array($link);
print_r($arr['@attributes']);
```

Comment: I have tested this, but does it also look if the `<link rel="alternate" hreflang....>` is actually present?

Comment: @Demian please see the edited answer.

Comment: Okay that seems complex, but that only checks for that specific string? It cannot just check if `<link>` element with attribute `hreflang` exists in the DOM?

Comment: I think that could be achieved with java script or jquery maybe. But with php you can not interact with DOM directly as it is a server side language and does not run in browser.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694640/find-an-element-in-dom-based-on-an-attribute-value

Comment: That makes sense. But I found the trigger here, your first suggestion with `!empty()` should be in this case `empty()`. So your first works without exclamation. Because my query `!($attribute['hreflang'])` the `!` = your `empty()`.